# Need to get the parent id but I'm getting level of the xml tag in Java

Tags: java, xml

Below is my XML

```
<jndi> 
    <ejbmodule> 
        <context>
            <leaf> 
                <name>XAConnectionFactory</name> 
                <type>type1</type> 
                <year>2002</year>
                <attribute name="class">org.jboss.mq.SpyXAConnectionFactory</attribute> 
                <test1>
                    <name>mytest</name>
                </test1>
            </leaf> 
            <name>java</name> 
            <type>type2</type> 
            <year>2003</year>           
            <leaf> 
                <name>DefaultDS</name> 
                <type>type3</type> 
                <year>2004</year>
                <attribute name="class">javax.sql.DataSource</attribute> 
            </leaf> 
        </context>
    </ejbmodule>    
</jndi>
```

Below is my java code where I'm traversing the XML and converting it to a DTree javascript code to display the XML as a tree structure on the html page

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class RecursiveDOM {

    static int globalCounter = 0;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        new RecursiveDOM("C:\\Users\\Rajani\\Downloads\\SampleXMLData\\dTree_1\\new1.xml");
    }

    public RecursiveDOM(final String file) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
        final DocumentBuilderFactory dbfac = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        final DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbfac.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileReader(new File(file)));
        final Document doc = docBuilder.parse(is);
        StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
        int parentId = -1;

        html.append("<div class=\"dtree\"><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"dtree.js\"></script>\n");
        html.append(createTreeCommandLinks("decisionReportTree"));
        // create tree and add root node
        html.append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n<!--\n");
        html.append("decisionReportTree = new dTree('decisionReportTree');\n");
        html.append("decisionReportTree.add(" + globalCounter++ + ",-1,'List Persons');\n");

        traverse(doc, parentId, html);

        html.append("document.write(decisionReportTree);");
        html.append("\n//-->\n</script>");
        System.out.println(html);
    }

    private static String add(String tree, int global, int parent, String name) {
        return tree + ".add(" + global + ", " + parent + ", '" + name + "');\n";
    }

    public static void traverse(Node node, int parentId, StringBuffer html) {
        handle_node(node, parentId, html);
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                Node kid = children.item(i);
                if (kid.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    traverse(kid, parentId + 1, html);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void handle_node(Node node, int parentId, StringBuffer html) {
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            String value = getNodeValue(node);

            if(null != value && value.trim().length() > 0) {
                html.append(add("decisionReportTree", globalCounter++, parentId, node.getNodeName() + ":::" + value));
            } else {
                html.append(add("decisionReportTree", globalCounter++, parentId, node.getNodeName()));
            }
        }
    }

    private static String createTreeCommandLinks(String treeName) {
        return "<p><a href=\"javascript: " + treeName + ".openAll();\">Expands all</a> | <a href=\"javascript: " + treeName + ".closeAll();\">Collapse all</a></p>";
    }

    protected static String getNodeValue(Node node) {
        NodeList childNodes = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int x = 0; x < childNodes.getLength(); x++) {
            Node data = childNodes.item(x);
            if (data.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE)
                return data.getNodeValue();
        }
        return "";
    }

    protected String getNodeAttrValue(String attrName, Node node) {
        NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();
        for (int y = 0; y < attrs.getLength(); y++) {
            Node attr = attrs.item(y);
            if (attr.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase(attrName)) {
                return attr.getNodeValue();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting with the above program is

```
decisionReportTree = new dTree('decisionReportTree');
decisionReportTree.add(0,-1,'List Persons');
decisionReportTree.add(1, 0, 'jndi');
decisionReportTree.add(2, 1, 'ejbmodule');
decisionReportTree.add(3, 2, 'context');
decisionReportTree.add(4, 3, 'leaf');
decisionReportTree.add(5, 4, 'name:::XAConnectionFactory');
decisionReportTree.add(6, 4, 'type:::type1');
decisionReportTree.add(7, 4, 'year:::2002');
decisionReportTree.add(8, 4, 'attribute:::org.jboss.mq.SpyXAConnectionFactory');
decisionReportTree.add(9, 4, 'test1');
decisionReportTree.add(10, 5, 'name:::mytest');
decisionReportTree.add(11, 3, 'name:::java');
decisionReportTree.add(12, 3, 'type:::type2');
decisionReportTree.add(13, 3, 'year:::2003');
decisionReportTree.add(14, 3, 'leaf');
decisionReportTree.add(15, 4, 'name:::DefaultDS');
decisionReportTree.add(16, 4, 'type:::type3');
decisionReportTree.add(17, 4, 'year:::2004');
decisionReportTree.add(18, 4, 'attribute:::javax.sql.DataSource');
document.write(decisionReportTree);
```

But I need the below output

```
decisionReportTree = new dTree('decisionReportTree');
decisionReportTree.add(0,-1,'List Persons');
decisionReportTree.add(1, 0, 'jndi');
decisionReportTree.add(2, 1, 'ejbmodule');
decisionReportTree.add(3, 2, 'context');
decisionReportTree.add(4, 3, 'leaf');
decisionReportTree.add(5, 4, 'name:::XAConnectionFactory');
decisionReportTree.add(6, 4, 'type:::type1');
decisionReportTree.add(7, 4, 'year:::2002');
decisionReportTree.add(8, 4, 'attribute:::org.jboss.mq.SpyXAConnectionFactory');
decisionReportTree.add(9, 4, 'test1');
decisionReportTree.add(10, 9, 'name:::mytest');
decisionReportTree.add(11, 3, 'name:::java');
decisionReportTree.add(12, 3, 'type:::type2');
decisionReportTree.add(13, 3, 'year:::2003');
decisionReportTree.add(14, 3, 'leaf');
decisionReportTree.add(15, 14, 'name:::DefaultDS');
decisionReportTree.add(16, 14, 'type:::type3');
decisionReportTree.add(17, 14, 'year:::2004');
decisionReportTree.add(18, 14, 'attribute:::javax.sql.DataSource');
document.write(decisionReportTree);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is passing `traverse(kid, parentId + 1, html)` for childs. The way you are doing, you are calculating the nodes depth, not transmiting annotating the father Id.

To get the desired result, you must pass the current and parent id on each interaction. Take a look at this example class:

```
public class Example {

    static Node root = new Node("List Persons",
    new Node("jndi",
            new Node("ejbmodule",
                new Node("context",
                    new Node("leaf",
                        new Node("name"),
                        new Node("type"),
                        new Node("year"),
                        new Node("attribute"),
                        new Node("test1", new Node("name"))
                    ),
                    new Node("name"),
                    new Node("type"),
                    new Node("year"),
                    new Node("leaf",
                        new Node("name"),
                        new Node("type"),
                        new Node("year"),
                        new Node("attribute")
                    )
                )
            )
    )
    );

    static int globalCounter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        traverse(root, globalCounter++, -1, null);

    }

    private static String add(String tree, int global, int parent, String name) {
        return tree + ".add(" + global + ", " + parent + ", '" + name + "');";
    }

    public static void traverse(Node node, int currentId, int parentId, StringBuffer html) {
        handle_node(node, currentId, parentId, html);
        //if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            //NodeList children = node.getChildNodes();
            for (Node kid : node.childs) {
                //Node kid = children.item(i);
                //if (kid.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    traverse(kid, globalCounter++ , currentId, html);
                //}
            }
        //}
    }

    public static void handle_node(Node node, int currentId, int parentId, StringBuffer html) {
        //if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            String value = node.value; //getNodeValue(node);

            System.out.println(add("decisionReportTree", currentId, parentId, value ));
            //if(null != value && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            //    html.append(add("decisionReportTree", currentId, parentId, node.getNodeName() + ":::" + value));
            //} else {
            //    html.append(add("decisionReportTree", currentId, parentId, node.getNodeName()));
            //}
        //}
    }
}
class Node {
    String value;
    Node[] childs;

    public Node(String value, Node... childs) {
        this.value = value;
        this.childs = childs;
    }

}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks Netto! This definitely works but how can I pass in a dynamic XML to the program? Do I need to convert the XML to Nodes each time and pass it in?

Comment: Ignore it Netto. I was able to figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nop. I used this example just to explain the id passing part. You may uncomment you XML handling statments and this should be fine.

Comment: Hi Netto, can you help me in adding little more logic to it? I need to traverse only selective nodes and their children from the xml. How can I add to the above logic?

Comment: what do you mean by selective nodes?

Comment: For eg: if I have a selection and If I select "leaf" from the above XML, i need to get all the nodes with leaf and its children.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean. Join this chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20089/need-to-get-the-parent-id-but-im-getting-level-of-the-xml-tag-in-java?tab=general

Comment: I can not chat here Netto... It is not letting me to chat here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

`traverse(kid, parentId + 1, html);`

Where you are passing `parentId + 1`, you should be supplying the id of the node whose children you are traversing.  To get it, change `handle_node` to *return* the id that it allocates to the node that is handles ...

Comment: Hi Stephen, How do I get the id of the node at that instant? I can't use the globalCounter there as it is exactly gives me the id of the node at that moment but if I pass the globalCounter then it is automatically treating as an increment which results both the globalCounter and parentId values for all the nodes as identical

Comment: As I said, you arrange that `handle_node` **returns** the node id that it has associated with the node.  And you then use that in the method that called `handle_node`.  Alternatively, allocate the id in the caller and pass it to `handle_node` as an extra argument.

Comment: Thanks Stephen... I was able to fix the issue.